# How to sort in ascending order a column of thousands of items based on the numbers included in their names?

Tags: sorting, element

The elements in my columns are named with text and numbers, like:
text1234
textsometext05
text147 etc.
My goal is to have those items sorted in ascending order based on those numbers, only, ignoring the text element of their names!
The end result should be:
whatevertext1
whatevermoretext2
...
...3000
...40000
and so on.
Does anyone know of a practical solution, please?
Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to provide a great deal more information to get an answer to this.  Firstly what language are you using?  Secondly have you even tried writing anything at all?  You'll get a lot more help if you at least put in the effort to try, and then show us what's not working so we can help you fix it.

Comment: Dgnuff, I don't really care if it is a script in any given language or just a few pre-set steps on a calc sheet. If there is a way to do it and it is in a language I don't know, then I will just learn the language in question. THE POINT is to hear from somebody who knows how to do it!